# How is & implemented in bash under the hood?

Tags: c, bash, background-process

```
&    # disown the functions
```

As we all know `&` put a task into background, and most importantly disowns the task.

But how is it achieved?

Comment: It does not disown the process on every system. On FreeBSD is does, on Linux not. See the `disown` function.

Comment: Nope. But just look if the `disown` function exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a `&`, the shell forks itself, calls `execve` in the child process to start the task, and waits via `wait` or `waitpid` for the child to terminate (which suspends the shell), not doing anything else than that.

When starting a background task, the shell forks itself again, calls `execve` to start the task in the child process, but doesn't wait for its termination and rather return the control immediately after the start of the task.

Comment: Bash doesn't always fork: sometimes execve is called directrly and sometimes commands are even executed internally depends on what and how you execute. It is strange that you specify execact functions that bash uses while you are so inaccurate in everything else. I think it will be good if you upgraded your post and added at least something about job control and stdin/stdout of child processes, but this is all imho.

Comment: I'm talking about the general way a shell starts an external program. Of course, to execute a built-in command a shell doesn't have to fork and exec since the code is in the same executable.